docker build not running npm commands
My container is being built but NPM commands seems to be not running.
I'm running docker-composer up app gulp for these services:
app:
  image: app_image
  container_name: myapp_app
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: _docker/app.Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html:delegated
  restart: always
  tty: true
  networks:
    - laravel

gulp:
  container_name: myapp_gulp
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: _docker/gulp.Dockerfile
  tty: true
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html:delegated
  networks:
    - laravel

The gulp.Dockerfile has:
FROM public.ecr.aws/ubuntu/ubuntu:18.04_stable

RUN apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y python2.7

ENV NODE_VERSION=11.15.0
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}
ENV PATH="/root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"

WORKDIR /var/www/html/_mytheme/tools
COPY . /var/www/html/

RUN npm install --python=python2.7
RUN npm i -y -g gulp@3.9.1 --python=python2.7
RUN npm i -y    gulp@3.9.1 --python=python2.7

RUN npm link gulp
RUN npm rebuild node-sass --python=python2.7

RUN npm i -g yarn --python=python2.7
RUN yarn install

ENTRYPOINT ["tail"]
CMD ["-f", "/dev/null"]

After the getting containers up, the NPM directories doesn't exists, like the npm install command didn't happened.
So I enter bash in container, run this command and that creates the node_modules folder fine.
Is there some reason for commands are not running?

You're mounting a volume over /var/www/html, which is part of your WORKDIR that you're running npm&yarn install from, so any directory created from building would be hidden

When you're defining .:/var/www/html in your volumes, whatever that was in /var/www/html is replaced with whatever is in your .. You'd have to rerun npm all over again.
